# A form that spits out the input

Tags: php, javascript, forms, templates

I can't for the life of me find a form that doesn't email the results that you submit.

I'm looking to find a form that I can have users enter simple data that i can then spit back out at them in different arrangements. If they submit First and Last, I'll spit out, amongst other things, FirstLast@domain.com. I'm willing to scrounge the code manually to do this, but I cant find a simple form that would allow me to do this.

**Edit:** PHP or similar simple languages. I've never touched .NET before.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would specify a coding language (and add a tag for it).

Comment: I don't see why this question is two up votes? I cannot event fully understand it... The internet is *full* of forms that don't email results around - what are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

Form:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    First: <input type="text" name="first" />
    Last: <input type="text" name="last" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Next page:

```
<?php

$first = $_POST['first'];
$last =  $_POST['last']

echo $first . "." . $last . "@domain.com";
?>
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp for more examples and explanation

Comment: You should call htmlentities() or htmlspecialchars() on any user input you spit back to the browser to prevent xss attacks

Comment: Totally agree with you on that one. Was just trying to keep the answer as simple and minimal as possible.

Comment: While you are at it... Look for characters invalid in e-mail addresses. Anyway: Wouldn't a form field that asks for the mail address be simpler or am I still missing the point?

Comment: If you agree, then please don't give bad advice and correct the example to escape properly.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how you get it, *always* remember to **never trust user input**.

```
<?php

$sfirst = htmlentities($_POST['first']);
$slast =  htmlentities($_POST['last']);

echo $first . "." . $last . "@domain.com";
?>
```

Also, running a validator on the final result may be helpful. But please don't write your own email address validator.

Comment: @orlandu63: strictly speaking, both should be applied. First rawurlencode() to convert from text to text-in-URL, and then htmlspecialchars() to convert from URL to URL-in-HTML.

In practice first escaping makes second unneccessary, but it doesn't mean that htmlspecialchars() shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

What language/platform/environment are you working in?

I guess you might be looking for a hosted script or webform (the way that people will host web-to-mail scripts I suppose) but I doubt there would be one out there that does this.

But if you have a specific framework to work in, e.g. PHP or .net, please update the question and let us know which.

Comment: (sitting next to ylight) - basic LAMP/PHP

Answer (score 0):

Thing that simple doens't even need server-side support.

```
<form onsubmit="magic(this);return false">
    <p><label>First <input name=first/></label>
    <p><label>Last <input name=last/></label>
    <input type="submit">

    <div id="output"></div>
</form>   

<script type="text/javascript">
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    function toHTML(text)
    {
        return text.replace(/</g,'&lt;');
    }

    function magic(form)
    {
        output.innerHTML = toHTML(form.first.value + form.last.value) + '@domain.com';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, sounds like this might do what you need..

**Note:** This PHP code doesn't require any knowledge of the fields in the form that submits to it, it just loops through all of the fields, including multiple-choice fields (like checkboxes), and spits out their values.

```
<?php
// loop through every form field
while( list( $field, $value ) = each( $_POST )) {
   // display values
   if( is_array( $value )) {
      // if checkbox (or other multiple value fields)
      while( list( $arrayField, $arrayValue ) = each( $value ) {
         echo "<p>" . $arrayValue . "</p>\n";
      }
   } else {
      echo "<p>" . $value . "</p>\n";
   }
}
?>
```